# Add sprite flickering to a LibGDX object

Tags: libgdx, sprites

**How can I make a LibGDX Actor object flicker over a set duration?**

Many 2D platformers have the player character 'flicker' after taking damage to indicate temporary invincibility, (ie: invincibility frames). For an example, see the below gif from Shovel Knight.

[image: Player taking damage from an enemy]

It's fairly simple to make an object fade in or out over time using [LibGDX's Actions library](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html).

```
Actor player = new Actor();
// fade out in 0.25 seconds
player.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(0.25));
```

But searching through the documentation, I couldn't find any method for `Actions.flicker()`. How can I implement sprite flickering in LibGDX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a flickering `SequenceAction` and have it repeat a preset number of times.

[image: flicker effect in action]

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;

if (playerDamaged) { 
    SequenceAction flicker = new SequenceAction(Actions.fadeOut(0.25f), Actions.fadeIn(0.25f));
    player.addAction(Actions.repeat(6, flicker));
}
```